# Handlebars duplicating ajax output on click

Tags: javascript, ajax, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars to print out a list of books, where if you click on the title of a book you get a new div showing details.  I'm able to print out the list and click on the book title to get details, but every title I click outputs the details from the first book that I clicked instead of the details for that book itself.  I believe this has something to do with binding but haven't found a syntax that seems to work.  Here's my HTML & Handlebars code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">  <div id="book-list-items"></div></div>
  <div id="book-details-items"></div>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <script id="book-list-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="book-list">
      <h3 class='template title'>{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script id="book-details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="book-details">
      <h3 class='template title'>{{title}}</h3>
      <h4 class='template year'>{{year}}</h4>
      <h4 class='template rating'>{{rating}}</h4>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var source = $('#book-list-template').html();
  var source2 = $('#book-details-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var template2 = Handlebars.compile(source2);

  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'https://....',
    data:{ api_key: '....'
    }
  }).done(
    function(data){
      populate_template(data)
    });

  var populate_template = function(data){
    data.results.forEach(function(book){
      var html = $(template(book));
      $('.main').append(html);
      html.click({book:book}, book_info)
    })
  }

  var book_info = function(event){
    id = event.data.book.id
    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: 'https://....' + id,
      data:{ api_key: '....'
      }
    }).done(function(data){
      var html2 = template2(data);
      $(document).trigger('change', event.currentTarget);
      $(document).on('change', function(e, listing){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(listing).replaceWith(html2)
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?  I assume it's in the #book-details-template script but am stuck on what the syntax would be.

Comment: Why do you trigger a change on the document and then bind a change handler after the trigger? Can't you just `$(event.currentTarget).replaceWith(html2)` ?

Comment: Aha, I overcomplicated it again.  This worked - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because the "change" listener on document stays active from the first call and in the followings call it's duplicated and so on... 
Try to eliminate the listener and put the template into the book-details-items:

$("#book-details-items").html(html2);

Comment: This gets me part of the way there, but I need to maintain the event.currentTarget (in lieu of "this").  Blake Simpson's comment above provides the complete solution.